# Can I split a single Django model field into multiple Django Rest Framework serializer fields?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to split a single m2m Django model field into multiple DRF serializer fields?

Consider the following code:

**models.py:**

```
class Author(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField()

class BookQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
  def good(self):
    return self.filter(is_good=True)

  def bad(self):
    return self.filter(is_good=False)

class Book(models.Model):
  objects = BookQuerySet.as_manager()

  title = models.CharField()
  author = models.ForeignKey(Author, related_name="books")
  is_good = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**serializers.py:**

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ["title"]

class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["name", "books"]

  books = BookSerializer(many=True)
```

Is there any way for me to *actually* serialize "books" as `good_books` and `bad_books`, but still have them map to the single `books` fields on the `Author` model?

Bear in mind, that these need to be writeable nested serializers.

Answer (score 4):

of course you can, define a serializeMethodField

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  books = BookSerializer(many=True) # here you get all books
  good_books = serializers.serializeMethodField()
  bad_books = serializers.serializeMethodField()
  
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["name", "books", "good_books", "bad_books"]

  def get_good_books(self, author):
      return BookSerializer(author.books.good()).data

  def get_bad_books(self, author):
      return BookSerializer(author.books.bad()).data
```

or:

```
class AuthorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  books =  serializers.serializeMethodField()
  
  class Meta:
    model = Author
    fields = ["name", "books"]

  def get_books(self, author):
      # bad and good books in the same key
      # result like:
      # "books": { "bad_books": [....list], "good_books": [...list}}
      return {
         "good_books": BookSerializer(author.books.good()).data,
         "bad_books": BookSerializer(author.books.bad()).data,
      }
```

Comment: Thanks.  Can I still use the custom BookSerializer class (and the custom ListSerializer class that it uses) w/ a SerializerMethodField (there is a lot of fancy code that I haven't shown in this small example)?